# how to fix setOpenableLayout in layout Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments

i have a problem why is setOpenableLayout not working?

```
mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
```

show error :

> error: cannot find symbol
> .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
> ^   symbol:   method setOpenableLayout(DrawerLayout)   location: class Builder

maybe someone here can help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your gradle config.

Look a problem of sdk versions. Try changing "`.setOpenableLayout(drawer)`" for "`.setDrawerLayout(drawer)`".

Anyway, it's possible for your minSdk method **setOpenableLayout** does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise to set higher version of androidx.navigation:navigation-ui (say 2.4.1).